# How to replace misspelled words with words from dictionary while ignoring text reference codes?

Tags: python, nltk, lstm, text-classification, lda

Topic modelling case here. So I've loaded my first round of preprocessed text data into a document term matrix, however looking at the dtm, I realized that there were words like 'aacc', 'aacct', 'aaccount' and a few different variations like that which basically just means accounts. Is there a way to replace those few words variations that meant account to the word account? I've tried the following code :

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

spell = SpellChecker()

# find those words that may be misspelled
misspelled = spell.unknown(['aacc'])

for word in misspelled:
    # Get the one `most likely` answer
    print(spell.correction(word))

    # Get a list of `likely` options
    print(spell.candidates(word))
```

but it doesn't actually give an output of the word to be 'account'. It's a little tricky as I'm looking to replace actual misspelled words from dictionary and ignore the other words that appears or seems to be misspelled but are just reference codes?

Also trying to remove duplicate characters in a string of sentence e.g 'tthe aabove aand areply tthankss'.

Hope I'm clear enough, thank you in advance.